# determine which of points A are within radius of other points B

Tags: r, r-sf

I would like to use `sf` to determine which `people` are located within 5km of any `cities`. In this example, `people` 1 and 2 should return as "Yes". They are located within 5km of Raleigh and Greensboro, respectively. 3 is not within 5km of any of these cities.

(This is a toy example that highlights the real use case.)

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)

cities <- data.frame(city = c("Raleigh", "Greensboro", "Wilmington"),
                     x = c(-78.633333, -79.819444, -77.912222),
                     y = c(35.766667, 36.08, 34.223333)) %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("x", "y"), crs = 4326) %>% 
  st_transform(2264) 

people <- data.frame(person = c(1:3),
                     x = c(-78.634899, -79.821140, -103.236804),
                     y = c(35.766266, 36.077911, 30.551109)) %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("x", "y"), crs = 4326) %>% 
  st_transform(2264) 

# adapted toy example from
# https://community.rstudio.com/t/sf-function-that-can-find-all-available-polygones-to-a-point-within-a-certain-radius/114318/2
```

Desired outout:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  person insideRad
   <dbl> <chr>    
1      1 Yes      
2      2 Yes      
3      3 No
```

Alternatively:

```
# A tibble: 9 × 3
  person city       insideRad
   <dbl> <chr>      <chr>    
1      1 Raleigh    Yes      
2      1 Greensboro No       
3      1 Wilmington No       
4      2 Raleigh    No       
5      2 Greensboro Yes      
6      2 Wilmington No       
7      3 Raleigh    No       
8      3 Greensboro No       
9      3 Wilmington No
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this piece of code; what it does is:

- combines all cities to a single multipoint, dropping data
- creates a buffer object around the multipoint; the linked example was kinda tongue in cheek, and used a CRS in survey feet. A metric crs - such as 3857 - might be more appropriate
- calculates whether the points objects are contained in the buffer; note the sparse = F setting, otherwise you would get a sparse matrix
- drop the points geometry & report result

```r
any_city_neigborhood <- cities %>% 
  st_geometry() %>% # geometry only
  st_union() %>% # combine to 1 row
  st_buffer(15000) # too lazy to calculate 5 Km in a feety CRS properly

# calculate intersection with the buffer object
people$close <- st_contains(any_city_neigborhood, people, sparse = F) [1,]

# report results
st_drop_geometry(people)
#   person close
# 1      1  TRUE
# 2      2  TRUE
# 3      3 FALSE
```

Comment: that's solid. thanks for taking the time to help.

Answer (score 0):

Taking inspiration from the toy example link provided in the OP:

```
cities_buffer <- st_buffer(cities, 3280.84 * 5)

out1 <- people %>%
  mutate(insideRad = ifelse(sf::st_intersects(people, buffer, sparse = F),
                            "Yes", 
                            "No")) %>%
  st_drop_geometry() %>%
  as_tibble()

out2 <- as_tibble(out1$insideRad)

out3 <- bind_cols(people$person, out2)
  
colnames(out3) <- c("person", cities$city)

out4 <- out3 %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(insideRad = if(any(str_detect(c_across(where(is.character)), 'Yes'))) 
    'Yes' else 'No') %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(person, insideRad)
```

I don't think my wrangling is efficient, but it returns:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  person insideRad
   <int> <chr>    
1      1 Yes      
2      2 Yes      
3      3 No
```